# Limit input to only numbers

Tags: c++, numeric, limits

This is part of my input value, what i want to do is to only input 0-9 however when i put an alphabet or any invalid key, they program works fine it ask to re enter.

invalid input please re-enter:

however this time when i re-enter it 
print out:[ 6.95324e-310 2 3 4 5 ]

here are the code:

```
int main()
{
   int aSize=5;
   double aArray[aSize];
   double value;

   for(int i=0;i<aSize;i++)
   {
      cout<<"enter value of slot"<<i+1<<": ";
      cin>>value;
      if(cin.fail())
      {
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
         cout<<"invalid input please re-enter: ";
         cin>>value;
      }
      else
      {
         aArray[i] = value;
         cout<<"value of aArray: "<<aArray[i];
      }
```

Comment: Somehow your indentation is totally trashed. Is it possible to clean this up and make it more readable?

Comment: 4 spaces per indent, no tabs. Readable code makes it easier to answer.

Comment: I fixed your indentation, but not your non-compilable code. I could try to fix it, but then I'd be making assumptions about how the code sample ends.

Comment: Is it on purpose that the user can only do one wrong entry ?  What happens if he makes a wrong entry the second time ?

Comment: @all basically what i wanna do is to capture the double value. if it not 0-9 it will ask to retype. but however this my code and instead of printing what i type e.g 
1,2,3,4,5
it print out weird number for the first i=0 i made

Comment: You should re-read the answer to your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24783190/624664)

Comment: @Christophe for as long as user input non numeric no it will return to re-enter value.

Comment: @Erbureth That is to ensure distinct value whereas this is to ensure numeric value entered.3

Comment: However it will also solve your specific problem.

Comment: @isme then the `if (cin.fail())` is not sufficient.  Use a `while(cin.fail())` instead and get rid of your `else` because I suppose you want to print the value as soon as you succeed in any case.

Comment: it reprint value exists multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter value of slot" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> value;
        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "invalid input please re-enter: ";
            cin >> value;
        }
        aArray[i] = value;
        cout << "value of aArray: " << aArray[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Fix the code flow, not all paths are supported.*

```
int main() {
  int aSize=5;
  double aArray[aSize];
  double value;

  for(int i=0;i<aSize;i++) {
    cout<<"enter value of slot"<<i+1<<": ";
    cin>>value;
// repeat handling of failure
    while (cin.fail()) {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      cout<<"invalid input please re-enter: "; 
// at this point we want to get back to fail
      cin>>value;
    }
    aArray[i] = value;
    cout<<"value of aArray: "<<aArray[i];

}
```